# See treeview for branches in Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, treeview, bitbucket-server

Is it possible to have a treeview for branches and commits like bitbucket or github has but in Atlassian Stash?

I would like a view like these:

http://blog.bitbucket.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/new-commits-screen-tn.png

http://blog.bitbucket.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/old-commits-screen.png

(they are both from bitbucket and represent the same commits, but it's just to show my idea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stash developer here. Unfortunately not. You might be interested in voting for the following:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2534

We're keen to get an idea of how people use this feature, and you want to add a comment to the ticket on your workflow that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite a bit old but I just wanted to inform anyone who might find this:

This feature is now available in Bitbucket Server 6.1

Release notes describing the feature: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-6-1-release-notes-966687591.html

Demonstration from that link:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be a feature of the Cloud version of Bitbucket as far as I can tell.